# VSTS-Build for SQL server project is not working

Tags: sql, azure, sql-server-data-tools

I have an Azure SQL Server database that I am  trying to put into `TFS`. I have created project and imported database, but when I try to do a build in Visual Studio I get the following error:

> "SQL71589: Master Key must be created before a database scoped
>   credential".

Answer (score 1):

You need to create scoped credentials for your database. See this MSDN article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Depending on your scenario, the code will look something like this:

```
-- Create a db master key if one does not already exist, using your own password.  
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='<EnterStrongPasswordHere>';  

-- Create a database scoped credential.  
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AppCred WITH IDENTITY = 'dbUserNameFooBar',   
    SECRET = '<EnterStrongPasswordHere>';  
GO
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i imported existing database in VSTS.In SSMS,it works fine